# TD class staying active when another TD class selected

Tags: javascript, class, html-table, dom-events

I need guidance editing a file. I have posted the Javascript below. This is a link to my working example http://www.closetos.com/top-shelf-awards_copy_copy.

The problem occurred when I added an additional row to the table. Now, when you select the text link in a cell in the second row, it stays selected and active, when clicking on something in the top row.

```
function $(id)
{
return document.getElementById(id);
}

function Coalesce(Value, Default)
{
if(Value == null)
return Default;

return Value;
}

function Switcher(numberOfSections, sectionContainerID, activeClass, inactiveClass)
{
this.NumberOfSections   = Coalesce(numberOfSections, 1) - 1;
this.SectionContainerID = Coalesce(sectionContainerID, "sectionContainer");
this.ActiveClass        = Coalesce(activeClass, "active");
this.InactiveClass      = Coalesce(inactiveClass, "");
}

Switcher.prototype.Switch = function(TheLink, SectionID)
{
// Make sure all sections are hidden
var SectionContainer = $(this.SectionContainerID);
for(var ct = 0; ct < SectionContainer.childNodes.length; ct++)
{
var node = SectionContainer.childNodes[ct];
if(node.nodeType != 1)
    continue;

node.style.display = "none";
}

var First = true;
// Reset button styles
for(var ct = 0; ct < TheLink.parentNode.childNodes.length; ct++)
{
if(TheLink.parentNode.childNodes[ct].nodeType != 1)
    continue;
else node = TheLink.parentNode.childNodes[ct];

node.className = this.InactiveClass;

if(First)
{
    node.className += " firstCell";
    First = false;
}
}

// Show the selected section
$(SectionID).style.display  = "block";

TheLink.className = this.ActiveClass;
if(TheLink == node)
TheLink.className += " lastCell";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is in this section of code. this looks only at the row that the clicked cell is in. `TheLink.parentNode` is a reference to the row that the cell is in.

```
for(var ct = 0; ct < TheLink.parentNode.childNodes.length; ct++) <--- parenNode == row
{
    if(TheLink.parentNode.childNodes[ct].nodeType != 1)
    {
         continue;
    }
    else 
    {
        node = TheLink.parentNode.childNodes[ct];
    }

    node.className = this.InactiveClass;

    if(First)
    {
        node.className += " firstCell";
        First = false;
    }
}
```

In order to make this work with multiple rows you need to modify it to look at other rows in the table:

```
for(var ct = 0; ct < TheLink.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes.length; ct++) 
    {   
        
        for( innerL = 0; innerL < TheLink.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[ct].childNodes.length; innerL++)
        { 
            if(TheLink.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[ct].childNodes[innerL].nodeType != 1)
            {
                 continue;
            }
            else 
            {
                node = TheLink.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[ct].childNodes[innerL];
            }
    
            node.className = this.InactiveClass;
    
            if(First)
            {
                node.className += " firstCell";
                First = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

in the block above you are looking at the parentNode's (the tr) parentNode (tbody) and then iterating through its grandchildren. This allows you to capture all the cells in the table, not just the row.

[Here is an example of it working.](http://tinkerbin.com/9wn5Gymg) When you follow the link you need to hit the green 'run' button on the bottom left of the page to get the script to load.

Comment: without being too egotistical, of course it worked perfect :). I am glad it helped. I f you want to learn more about javascript I find the best way is by doing. If you have not messed around with jsfiddle or tinkerbin, I would highly suggest trying some experimentation out on one of those sites to get familiar with functionality.

Comment: Need some more help. I created a new tinkerbin file http://tinkerbin.com/7bWc3m0x. The issue is i switched the link in the first cell to "Cherry and Leather Indulgence" when the page loads, it is still showing the "Farmhouse with Flair" Photo and text instead of the "Cherry & Leather Indulgence" image and text. I switched the td class="active". I am stuck once again. I would appreciate any help. This is my nightmare project.

Comment: Do you want an answer or a hint?

Comment: A million thank you's!!!! A hint or an answer to see what you did so I can learn instead of just copy code.

Comment: Pay close attention to the default styles of those sections. You will notice that they all say 'display:none;' except for one.

Comment: I knew it was something simple. I can't believe I missed that! I was thinking it had to be something with the js. Thanks again.

Comment: It was easy to miss. I thought it had to do with the JS also but after I realized there was no initialization from the script, that it had to be something with the styles. Glad it helped.